# While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

/azure-release-pipeline-template.yml@templates (Line: 110, Col: 5):  While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.
i am getting above error for this line (- script: exit 1 )

- bash: |
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=mySecretPAT;issecret=true]${{ parameters.pat }}"

## pat must be specified

```
- script: exit 1
  displayName: Fail if pat not specified
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.pat }}', 'NA')
```

## Setup

```
- script: |
    git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
    git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
  displayName: Setup for build
```

- checkout: self
  submodules: true
  persistCredentials: true

i tried this sccript not understand please help

Answer (score 1):

It simply states that it does not find a parameter you are referencing in the condition:

```
condition: eq('${{ parameters.pat }}', 'NA')
```

See [use parameters in pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines) documentation.

Just define the pat parameter and it will work

```yaml
parameters:
- name: pat
  type: string
  default: 'NA'
```